# Class with std::istream reference initialization

Tags: c++, class, istream, member-initialization

I'm having problems initializing this class:

```
class Player{
  ///
  std::istream &in;
  ///
};
```

Trying like this:

```
Player::Player():in(cin){
  ///
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this?
Also, after initialization, can I change the reference by saying something like

```
stringstream ss("test");
Player p;
p.in = ss;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can only initialize references and you can't change them later. The most you can do is assign new values to what is being referenced, but not the reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the constructor, only defined it. 
Declare the constructor and set it public:

```
class Player{
public:
  Player(); // You need to declare the constructor
  std::istream &in;
};

Player::Player():in(cin)
{}

int main()
{
    Player p;
}
```

> can I change the reference?

No, you can't change the reference, only values to what is being referenced.

Comment: @NicholasPaxton You want it public to easily access it from main.